# Pretty NSString from NSDate interval?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

Does anyone know a good or simplest way to get a short pretty string from a date interval? I would like to enter two dates and get an as simple string as possible, i.e.

```
[2015-01-03 .. 2015-01-05] would output "Jan 3-5, 2015"
[2015-01-03 .. 2015-02-01] would output "Jan 3 - Feb 1, 2015"
[2015-01-03 .. 2016-02-01] would output "Jan 3, 2015 - Feb 1, 2016"
```

I could even imagine adding hours, minutes and seconds to the above

```
[2015-01-03 08:00:00 .. 2015-01-03 10:00:00] would output "8-10 am, Jan 3, 2015"
```

Then there's the issue of localizing, so that in swedish the first example would be:

```
[2015-01-03 .. 2015-01-05] would output "3-5 jan, 2015"
```

Comment: This is what [`NSDateIntervalFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateIntervalFormatter_class/index.html) is for.

Comment: Well, that was a bit embarrassing, thank @KenThomases!

Comment: You're welcome. It's new, so still not very well known.